# How to get hotel total room and booked room in single query

Tags: mysql

How to get hotel total room and booked room in single query.

I used 2 queries get result. I need this in single query.

The issue I am experiencing since all counts are in this table htl_room_information.id_hotel

Booked room:

```
 SELECT x.hotel_name
      , count(i.id_hotel) room 
   FROM htl_booking_detail d
   JOIN htl_branch_info_lang x
     ON x.id=d.id_hotel 
   JOIN htl_room_information i 
     ON d.id_room=i.id 
  group 
     by x.hotel_name;

+------------------------------------------+------+
| hotel_name                               | room |
+------------------------------------------+------+
| hotel                                    |    3 |
| hotel1                                   |    1 |
| hotel2                                   |    4 |
| hotel3                                   |   13 |
| hotel4                                   |    9 |
| hotel5                                   |    3 |
| hotel6                                   |    3 |
| hotel7                                   |    2 |
+------------------------------------------+------+
```

Total Rooms

```
SELECT (htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name) as hotel_name,count(htl_room_information.id_hotel) as total_room FROM htl_room_information ,htl_branch_info_lang where htl_room_information.id_hotel=htl_branch_info_lang.id group by htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name;

+------------------------------------------+------------+
| hotel_name                               | total_room |
+------------------------------------------+------------+
| hotel                                    |        219 |
| hotel2                                   |         25 |
| hotel3                                   |         16 |
| hotel4                                   |          5 |
| hotel5                                   |         55 |
| hotel6                                   |         27 |
| hotel7                                   |         56 |
| hotel8                                   |         52 |
+------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: What's wrong with two queries?

Comment: I need that 2 quarries together to get the counts of total room and booked room in single query. Then I attache this to our dashboard of metabase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use subquery
try this:

```
SELECT (a.hotel_name) as 
hotel_name,count(htl_room_information.id_hotel) as total_room, (SELECT 
count(htl_room_information.id_hotel) as room FROM htl_booking_detail, 
htl_branch_info_lang b, htl_room_information  WHERE 
b.id=htl_booking_detail.id_hotel and  
htl_booking_detail.id_room=htl_room_information.id and 
b.hotel_name = a.hotel_name), count(htl_room_information.id_hotel) - (SELECT 
count(htl_room_information.id_hotel) as room FROM htl_booking_detail, 
htl_branch_info_lang b, htl_room_information  WHERE 
b.id=htl_booking_detail.id_hotel and  
htl_booking_detail.id_room=htl_room_information.id and 
b.hotel_name = a.hotel_name) as available  FROM htl_room_information 
,htl_branch_info_lang 
a where htl_room_information.id_hotel=a.id group by 
a.hotel_name;
```

Comment: Dear Renz, its not working, I can see below error: java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: now I am getting below error: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name' in 'field list'

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad sorry i'm no expert, just trying to help but edited it again, can you try.

Comment: @ Renz its now working fine. Thank you very much. Now I need difference between the count as well

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad Glad i helped, can you please upvote my answer and accept it as correct

Comment: voted thanks.  where I can add From date column in between query so that i can filter this by date

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad just after the GROUP BY will do

Comment: The thing is if I select different dates, its not calculating "Available Room" Actually avalable room should change by date. But its not calculating. How can I get the correct calculation. where caluse I have added this {{from_date}}   to get the result datewsie and inbetween dates. Bit its not caculating Available rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

Please check below query.

```
select b.hotel_name hotel_name, a.room , 
b.total_room
from
(SELECT htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name, 
count(htl_room_information.id_hotel) as room FROM htl_booking_detail, 
htl_branch_info_lang, htl_room_information WHERE 
htl_branch_info_lang.id=htl_booking_detail.id_hotel and  
htl_booking_detail.id_room=htl_room_information.id group by 
htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name ) a RIGHT join (SELECT (htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name) as 
hotel_name,count(htl_room_information.id_hotel) as total_room 
FROM htl_room_information ,htl_branch_info_lang 
where htl_room_information.id_hotel=htl_branch_info_lang.id 
group by htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name) b
on a.hotel_name = b.hotel_name
;
```

Comment: Dear Tajinder, I am getting below error:  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'full outer join (SELECT (htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name) as  hotel_name,count(h' at line 1

Comment: In case, it helped, requesting you to please upvote the answer, SeeSo that other users also get help.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, the thing is I need Available room=total room -booked room     How can I achive this by date wise or in between dates. I use metabase to select the dates in query.

Answer (score 0):

Use dependent subqueries.

```
SELECT x.hotel_name,
    (
      SELECT count(i.id_hotel)  
      FROM htl_booking_detail d
      JOIN htl_room_information i 
         ON d.id_room=i.id 
      WHERE x.id=d.id_hotel 
    ) as room,
    (
      SELECT count(i.id_hotel) 
      FROM htl_room_information i
      WHERE i.id_hotel=x.id 
    ) as total_room 
FROM htl_branch_info_lang x
```

I assume that the `hotel_name` is unique in the `htl_branch_info_lang` table. If not, you have to put `distinct` behind the first `SELECT`.